# Meteor app suddenly no longer runs on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, meteor

My Meteor-based app no longer works as designed on iOS, without me having changed anything relevant. The app still works when run from a local server (http://localhost:3000) as well as when hosted at meteor.com. But, in an iOS simulator and when deployed to an iOS device through xCode, the app fails to run properly.

The app opens with a form that needs to be filled in by the user. When submitting the form, on iOS, the entered values briefly are stored in session variables, but almost immediately the session variables are emptied and the form is displayed again. (What should happen is for an external JSON file to be loaded, based on the form values, after which the contents of that JSON file is manipulated and displayed.)

I just now upgraded to the latest version of Meteor, and xCode did an upgrade itself in the background.

The app is supposed to load a Google font file (from fonts.googleapis.com), but though this works fine when the app is served from either the localhost or meteor, the font does not appear to be loaded when the app runs on iOS.

I'm sorry I don't have actual example code (the whole app?) or a running version of the app that I can show you. As the app is not yet publicly available, I'm a bit reluctant to publish it here. :(

Is there a way to meaningfully debug a Meteor app running on iOS? Is there something obvious I'm missing in the deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there's an issue with meteor 1.0.4 and building a project using Cordova (https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3814).

I downgraded to meteor 1.0.3 through:

```
meteor update --release 1.0.3
```

Then, I deleted the Cordova folder in .meteor/local/ with

```
rm -R cordova-build
```

Then, I patched 1.0.3 to 1.0.3.2 with

```
meteor update --patch
```

This solved the problem.